# When looping through values of a JS array, and I remove value, do I need to use while instead of for?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function isOdd(value){
    return value % 2;
}

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    if(isOdd(myArray[i])){
        myArray.splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

The code above takes an array of arbitrary length and checks each value. If the value of the bit of the array meets an arbitrary condition (in this case if it is odd), then it is removed from the array.

`Array.prototype.splice()` is used to remove the value from the array, and then `i` is decremented to account for the rest of the values in the array "moving down" to fill in the gap that the removed value left (so the loop doesn't skip over a value).

However, the `for` loop ends when `i` equals the length of the array, which gets shorter as values are removed.

Does the value of `myArray.length` decrease dynamically as the loop proceeds, or does it save the value at the start of the loop and not update as values are removed? If the latter, what can I do to fix my loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myArray.length` is changing with the operation on the array. But looping and splicing leads to unwanted results, if not proper padded.

To prevent unnecessary corrections, use a while loop from the end, to keep the rest of the array for processing.

```js
function isOdd(value) {
    return value % 2;
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    i = myArray.length;

while (i--) {
    if (isOdd(myArray[i])) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the higher-order `Array.prototype.filter()` method is the better choice for this sort of operation. Code depending on the `filter()` method is considerably more concise and, I would say, considerably more readable.

Comment: you are right, but the problem is one with splice, and the drawbacks of it with looping.

Comment: @Tex - `.filter()` is certainly easier to use, but it creates a new array rather than modifying the original array which is not the same implementation as the OP has.  Sometimes, if other code has a reference to this array, you want to modify the array rather than replace with a new one.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's generally considered better practice to create a new array rather than modify an existing one, but if the asker absolutely needs to modify the existing array, they can simply set the value of the existing one to the result of `.filter()`.

Comment: @NinaScholz  I would argue that the better answer would be to direct the asker to avoid `splice()` and use `.filter()` instead, while also explaining why `.splice()` is not working as the asker hoped it would in their original code sample.

Comment: @Tex - Whether it is appropriate to create a new array or modify the current one depends entirely upon the programming situation.  You can't say it's always a "better practice" to create a new array.  If 10 objects have a reference to this master array, then you may have to modify it rather than create a new one in order to achieve the desired effect.  It depends upon the programming situation.  I'm just pointing out that your recommendation does NOT provide the exact same "in place" modification that the OP's code was intending to do.  That may be OK or may not, depending upon the situation.

Comment: @jfriend00 While it is sometimes appropriate to modify a variable in-place, the more modern paradigm in javascript is to program in more functional way, avoiding the modification of existing variables unless otherwise necessary. And as I stated in my previous reply to you, the original array can be modified by simply assigning the value of the `filter()` operation to it.

Comment: @Tex - Assign the filter result back does not modify the original array at all.  That would not affect any other objects that have a reference to the original array.  That points the current variable at the newly created array (which is sometimes all that is needed), but does not modify the original array.  You don't seem to understand the case where other code has a reference to this same array which is when a modification of the original array object may be appropriate. We don't need to discuss any further.  I like `.filter()`.  Just pointing out it wasn't identical in function.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand that and misspoke. Assigning the result of `filter()` to the original variable modifies the original variable, not the original array. If the asker MUST modify the original array, `splice()` is the correct option, but I would argue that `filter()` is a better option otherwise.

Comment: Is that OK to use delete which wont change the size of array but makes unassigned indices?

Comment: @mortezaT, it depends on the context. if you have to maintain the indices, then yes, in all other cases maybe no.

Answer (score 0):

The `length` property is read in every iteration, and the splice method does update its value, so it works as you would expect. However, I would say that this is not a good coding practice, a `while` loop is much more readable, so it should be the obvious choice.

To answer the question directly: you *don't have to* use `while` instead of `for`, but you definitely *should*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.filter` instead

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
myArray=myArray.filter(function(item,index) {
 return !(item % 2);
})

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you'd want to use `Array.prototype.filter()` if you don't absolutely HAVE to modify the original array, in-place.

As you suspect, the `.length` property of the array is being updated every time you `splice()`. The `filter()` method was built for exactly this sort of operation.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function isOdd(value){
    return value % 2;
}

var filteredArray = myArray.filter(function(item){
  return !isOdd(item);
});
    
console.log(filteredArray);
```

A more concise version of the above code:

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function isEven(value){
  return value % 2 === 0;
}
    
var filteredArray = myArray.filter(isEven);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

An even more concise version relying on ES6 arrow syntax:

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var isEven = value => value % 2 === 0;
    
var filteredArray = myArray.filter(isEven);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

And, in the event that you absolutely MUST edit the array in-place / use `splice()` here, I would recommend using `Array.prototype.forEach()` over a `for` or `while` loop. `forEach()` is another higher order method that allows you to realize the same functionality with less boilerplate. As with most higher order methods/functions, it allows you to focus on defining what you need to do rather than exactly how it needs to be done.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function isOdd(value){
    return value % 2;
}

myArray.forEach(function(c, i, a){
    if(isOdd(c)){
        a.splice(i,1);
    }
})

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them and it's depends on which one you like. if you prefer to use `while loop` then Nina's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37854033/3078890) looks good and if you want to use `for loop` then consider to manage counter changes by yourself completely or when the length changes:

```js
function isOdd(value) {
  return value % 2;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length;)
  isOdd(arr1[i]) ? arr1.splice(i, 1) : i++;
console.log(arr1);

var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
  if (isOdd(arr2[i])) {
    arr2.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
console.log(arr2);
```